# Error propagation through two consecutive regressions

Tags: regression, error-propagation

I have one linear regression between a variable of interest (z) and measured values of another variable (y):

z = ay + b

and another regression between y and a proxy variable (x):

y = cx + d

I want to make the case that x is a reasonable proxy for y in estimating z, using these two consecutive regressions. Can I calculate the r2 for the regression between z and predicted y, accounting for the error produced by predicting y from z?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: The question is confusing.  Do you mean that you want to show that x is also a good predictor of z?  Also are you saying you only have the summary stats on x and not the individual x values.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Basically, I want to calculate the error in z when I measure x, predict y from x, and then predict z from y. I want to compare that error to the error in z predicted directly from y. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by simplifying the situation.  By centering and scaling all data variables appropriately we may create new ones $X,Y,Z$ whose averages are zero and whose lengths, thought of as Euclidean vectors, are unity.  When this is done, as is well-known, the regression models are equivalent to

$$Z = \alpha Y + \varepsilon_{ZY}$$

and

$$Y = \gamma X + \varepsilon_{YX}$$

and the errors $\varepsilon_{ZY}$ and $\varepsilon_{YX}$ still have zero means and are independent (within each model).  The least-squares solutions are the cosines of the angles among these (unit vectors), $\hat\alpha=\cos(ZY)$ and $\hat\gamma = \cos(YX)$.  These cosines are usually called the *correlation coefficients.*  Their squares are the $R^2$ statistics for the regressions (which haven't changed as a result of the centering and scaling).

Using $x$ as a proxy for $y$ is equivalent to using $X$ as a proxy for $Y$.  When that occurs, the least squares estimate in the model

$$Z = \beta X + \varepsilon_{ZX}$$

is $\hat\beta = \cos(ZX)$. This allows us to recast the question as one of (three-dimensional) Euclidean geometry:

> How well can the (cosine of the) angle $XY$ be estimated based on estimates of the cosines of the other two angles, $ZY$ and $YX$?

The answer is fairly obvious from pictures: **the angle $XY$ cannot be any greater than the sum of $ZY$ and $YX$ and it cannot be any less than the size of the difference of $ZY$ and $YX$.**  (This statement needs appropriate modification when the sum exceeds $90$ degrees: I'll leave that for the interested reader to work out.)

As an extreme example, suppose both angles are $45$ degrees: thus, their cosines are each $\sqrt{1/2} \approx 0.71$ (which is often considered a largish correlation) and both $R^2$ statistics are $1/2$.  The angle $XZ$ may range from $45+45=90$ degrees down to $|45-45|=0$ degrees.  In the former case, $Z$ and $X$ are *orthgonal* and $\hat\beta=0$: there is no "linear relation" between them, so $X$ is the worst possible proxy for $Y$.  In the latter case $X$ and $Z$ are perfectly correlated and $X$ is the best possible proxy for $Y$.

Contemplation of a few such examples leads one to conclude that unless both $R^2$ statistics (for $Z$ against $Y$ and $Y$ against $X$) are sufficiently close to $1$, it is possible $X$ would be a poor proxy for $Y$.  As an approximation, if by "good proxy" you mean the $R^2$ for $Z$ *vs* $X$ will be at least some (moderately large) threshold $C$, then you will want $R^2_{ZY} + R^2_{ZX} - 1$ to exceed $C$ to assure this.

[image: Figure]

*This figure shows $X$ situated relative to $Y$.  Given the depicted angle between $Z$ and $Y$, the possible locations of $Z$ lie on the red spherical circle shown.  Parts of this circle (near the right) are relatively close to $X$, but other parts (near the back left) are nearly at right angles to $X$. Depending on where $Z$ actually is on that circle, $X$ might or might not be close to ("a good proxy") for $Y$.*

---

An `R` implementation to simulate a dataset of any size and any valid set of correlation coefficients (as specified by angles or directly by modifying `rho`) follows.  It will enable you to experiment with the possibilities.

```R
library(MASS) # exports `mvrnorm`
#
# Specify dataset properties.
# The angle ZX must lie between the extremes of XY+YX and |XY-YX| in order
# for the specified dataset to be possible.
# 
n <- 30                 # Dataset size
alpha <- 45 / 180 * pi  # Angle XY (in radians)
gamma <- 45 / 180 * pi  # Angle YX (in radians)
beta <- 90 / 180 * pi   # Angle ZX (in radians)
#
# Generate a dataset with the specified correlations.
#
rho <- c(xy=cos(gamma), xz=cos(beta), yz=cos(alpha)) # Correlations
Sigma <- matrix(rep(rho, 5)[c(-1,-2,-15)], 4)[-4, ]  # Correlation matrix
diag(Sigma) <- 1
xyz <- try(as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n, c(x=0,y=0,z=0), Sigma, empirical=TRUE)),
           silent=TRUE)
if ("try-error" %in% class(xyz)) stop("These angles are inconsistent.")
#
# Display the three regression results.
#
summary(lm(z ~ y, xyz))$r.squared
summary(lm(y ~ x, xyz))$r.squared
summary(lm(z ~ x, xyz))$r.squared
```